# Como redirecionar todo o script bash dentro do próprio script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

Eu preciso jogar a saída dele em um arquivo ao invés de jogar na saída padrão que é a tela mas sem eu ter que explicitar com o comando `>>` no terminal, quero que o próprio script faça isso.

Comment: *onde eu só executo ele e ele ja se auto redireciona?* Pode ser mais claro? ficou bem confusa sua pergunta.

Comment: Então, eu quero jogar a saída dele em um arquivo ao invés de jogar na saída padrão que é a tela mas sem eu ter que explicitar com o >> no terminal,, quero que o próprio script faça isso.

Comment: O que você quer é algo como: `echo $SHELL >  /tmp/teste` sendo executado dentro do script?

Comment: Se for o que entendi, você pode fazer o redirecionamento que faria no terminal dentro do próprio script, setando um arquivo de saída para os comandos ao invés da saída padrão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
{
   #seus comandos bash aqui
} > output.txt 2>&1
```

OBS: Se você não especificar o caminho do output, o arquivo será gerado no diretório em que o script bash está.